# Como limpar o Google Blockly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu estou utilizando no meu projeto o Google Blockly e preciso que quando eu clicar em um botão, esvazie a estrutura montada que está na memória.
Como posso fazer?

https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/overview

Meu exemplo: Eu preciso inserir um botão para deletar tudo que estiver no workspace

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Blockly Demo: Fixed Blockly</title>
   <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-102948379-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
   </script>
   <script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
   <script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
   <script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/msg/js/en.js"></script>
   <style>
  body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 140%;
  }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1><a href="https://developers.google.com/blockly/">Blockly</a> &gt;

   <p>This is a simple demo of injecting Blockly into a fixed-sized 'div' element.</p>

   <p>&rarr; More info on <a href="https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure-blockly/web/fixed-size">injecting fixed-sized Blockly</a>&hellip;</p>

   <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>

   <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
  <block type="controls_if"></block>
  <block type="logic_compare"></block>
  <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
  <block type="math_number"></block>
  <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
  <block type="text"></block>
  <block type="text_print"></block>
   </xml>

   <script>
  var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
   {media: '../../media/',
    toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
   </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Etapa 2

Será que tem como atribuir o ID a cada bloco de codigo separado ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Não seria o [`Workspace.clear()`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#clear)? Você chegou a pesquisar na documentação?

Comment: Sim cheguei, mas não estou entendendo como funciona esse Workspace.clear()

Comment: É deste codigo que vocês precisam ? E para não confundir a cabeça das pessoas que queiram usar este post para aprender, eu deletei algumas respostas, para simplificar e deixar o post focado.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu comentei, basta utilizar o [`Worspace.clear`](https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#clear). O objeto do `workspace` você já tem no JavaScript, basta chamar o método `clear` ao pressionar o botão. Veja:

```js
var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
  media: '../../media/',
  toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')
});

var button = document.getElementById("clear");

button.addEventListener("click", event => {
   workspace.clear();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/msg/js/en.js"></script>

<button id="clear">Limpar</button>

<div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>

<xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
  <block type="controls_if"></block>
  <block type="logic_compare"></block>
  <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
  <block type="math_number"></block>
  <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
  <block type="text"></block>
  <block type="text_print"></block>
</xml>
```

Comment: Nossa que dahora. Obrigado. Será que da para detectar blocos diferentes separados ? Vou postar a imagem no meu post

Comment: @abduzeedo não fez muito sentido o que perguntou e a imagem que colocou na pergunta não ficou clara. Pode explicar, em palavras, exatamente o que precisa? E busque não alterar o objetivo inicial da pergunta. Se possui outra dúvida diferente da que foi respondida, você deve abrir uma nova pergunta.